# C# vs JAVA instance of Interface

Tags: java, c#, android

I am not sure how am I suppose to go about my question. It is about Android can Instantiate Interface. I am trying to do in C#. Now I am pretty sure that the rules for both Java and C# is you can't create an Instance of abstract and Interface as being said.

But I would really like to know how Android does this practice.

In Android you can do this.

```
public interface Checkme{
    void Test();
    void Test2();
}


public void myFunc(Checkme my){
  //do something
}

// Now this is the actual usage.

public void Start(){

   myFunc(new Checkme(){
       @Override
       public void Test()
       {


       }
       @Override
       public void Test2()
       {


       }
    });

}
```

Actually once you press Enter on `new Checkme()` You will automatically get the Override methods of the Interface. Like auto Implement method of an Interface in C#.

I hope my question make sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you talking about a code-completion feature of an IDE?

Comment: This is called an anonymous class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: No, not about the code completion. In android. This is a very common practice. For example ` swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipyRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {` We instantiated a new Interface.OnRefreshListener

Comment: Thanks, dharms, do you think I can do the same for C#?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# doesn't support anonymously auto-implemented interfaces because it has *delegates*:

```
public void Foo(Func<string> func, Action action) {}

// call it somewhere:
instance.Foo(() => "hello world", () => Console.WriteLine("hello world"));
```

With delegates you can fill the gap and it can be even more powerful than implementing interfaces with anonymous classes.

[Learn more about delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

Comment: I know about delegates. But not so deep into it that I can use for a new Structure approach for coding. There is a lot of ways we can do on delegates but on my level, I am ended up trying to look for the use of it being tedious than to straight code from non delegate approach. Thanks for the link Matias

Comment: A delegate is equivalent to the Java 8 lambda expression, but is not equivalent to anonymous classes for interfaces and abstract classes with more than one abstract method.

Comment: @Andreas I've never said that it's the same. My answer tells the OP that C# doesn't support this feature but it provides delegates instead. I believe that I'm not mistaken, am I? :D

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer True, and I get the distinction, but you never made it clear that delegates are for single methods only, and as such is **not an answer** to this particular question, given that the question has *two* methods in the interface. It's a valid contribution though.

Comment: @Andreas I believe the OP realized that it can be easily emulated with methods with more than a delegate as input parameters...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Accepted. I'd suggest you make that an explicit suggestion in your answer, for other readers that come here in the future.

Comment: @Andreas I've edited it to show a method that accepts two delegates as input parameters

Answer (score 4):

This is an [Anonymous Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html):

```
public void Start(){
    myFunc(new Checkme() {
        @Override
        public void Test() {
        }
        @Override
        public void Test2() {
        }
    });
}
```

An anonymous class is an unnamed class implemented inline.

You could also have done it using a [Local Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html), but those are rarely seen in the wild.

```
public void Start(){
    class LocalCheckme implements Checkme {
        @Override
        public void Test() {
        }
        @Override
        public void Test2() {
        }
    }
    myFunc(new LocalCheckme());
}
```

These both have the advantage that they can use method parameters and variables directly, as long as they are (effectively) final.

As a third option, you could do it with an [Inner Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

```
private class InnerCheckme implements Checkme {
    @Override
    public void Test() {
    }
    @Override
    public void Test2() {
    }
}
public void Start(){
    myFunc(new InnerCheckme());
}
```

An inner class cannot access method variables (obviously because it's outside the method), but can be used by multiple methods.

Any local values from the method can however be passed into the constructor and stored as fields of the inner class, to get the same behavior. Just requires a bit more code.

If the inner class doesn't need access to fields of the outer class, it can be declared `static`, making it a [Static Nested Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

So, all 3 ways above a very similar. The first two are just Java shorthands for the third, i.e. *syntactic sugar* implemented by the compiler.

**C# can do the third one**, so just do it that way for C#.

Of course, if the interface only has one method, using a Java *lambda* or C# *delegate* is much easier than Anonymous / Local / Inner classes.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correcly, you're defining a class that implements an interface, and when you specify that the class implements an interface, you want it to automatically add the interface's methods and properties.

If you've declared this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoSomething();
}
```

And then you add a class:

```
public class MyClass : ISomeInterface // <-- right-click
{
}
```

Right-click on the interface and Visual Studio will give you an option to implement the interface, and it will add all the interface's members to the class.

Comment: That is correct Scott Hannen, Actually you can use CTRL + . if you want hot key short cuts. But my Question is about Creating an Instance of the Interface. On your answer, you Inherit from it. I am very sorry if my question misleads you to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like this?

```
pulic interface Foo{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Bar : Foo {
    public void DoSomething () {
        //logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm no, that is Inheriting the Contract my question is about creating an Instance of it. You need to add virtual if you need to override by the way.

Comment: @Matias: of course you are totally right. Fixed it. Remember: always read twice what you have written :)

Comment: @Aizen: has just been a guess. I found the question to be very unclear and hard to understand.

Comment: Yes I understand, I am sorry about my question being so broad and misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
myFunc(new Checkme(){
   @Override
   public void Test()
   {


   }
   @Override
   public void Test2()
   {


   }
});
```

You're passing into myFunc() something that is called an anonymous class. When it says "new Checkme() { .... }", it is defining an anonymous implementation of the Checkme interface. So, it's not an instance of the interface itself, just an instance of a type that implements it.

Comment: A lambda is not an anonymous class or vice-versa. A lambda can be used as an alternative to an anonymous class for any class/interface with exactly one abstract method. Lambdas cannot be used when more than one method is abstract, as is the case here.

Comment: My mistake, will edit out Lambda. I was not aware there was any formal difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

In C# anonymously implemented classes for Interface are not auto generated just like in java, you need to follow the below procedure to workout.

```cs
public class MyClass {

    public void someMethod (string id, IMyInterface _iMyInterface) {

        string someResponse = "RESPONSE FOR " + id;

        _iMyInterface.InterfaceResponse (someResponse);

    }

}

public interface IMyInterface {
    void InterfaceResponse (object data);
    void InterfaceResponse2 (object data, string x);
}

public class MyInterfaceImplementor : IMyInterface {
    private readonly Action<object> actionname;
    private readonly Action<object, string> actionInterfaceResponse2;

    public MyInterfaceImplementor (Action<object> InterfaceResponse) {
        this.actionname = InterfaceResponse;
    }

    public MyInterfaceImplementor(Action<object> interfaceResponseMethod, Action<object, string> interfaceResponseMethod1) {
        this.actionname = interfaceResponseMethod ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(interfaceResponseMethod));
        this.actionInterfaceResponse2 = interfaceResponseMethod1 ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(interfaceResponseMethod1));
    }

    public void InterfaceResponse (object data) {
        this.actionname (data);
    }
    
    public void InterfaceResponse2(object data, string x) {
        this.actionInterfaceResponse2(data, x);
    }
}
```

> Gist Source : https://gist.github.com/pishangujeniya/4398db8b9374b081b0670ce746f34cbc

Reference :