# C# equivalent to implement interface inside super keyword in Java

Tags: java, c#, super

I have this piece of Java code which I would like to implement in C#, but I have two main problems:

1. I had never seen this Java syntax before. I am not sure what is it
   actually doing. Is the first parameter in the constructor super
   implementing the interface ObjectFactory to retrieve a new Object of
   type Edge, I think!
2. I am quite new to C# so I am not sure of how I could do this.

This is the piece of **Java** code:

```
static class Edges extends UpdatableRepository<Edge> {
    Edges(final DataInputStream dis, final DataOutputStream dos, StringListQ idListQuery) {
        super(new ObjectFactory<Edge>() {
            public Edge newObject(String objectID) {
                return new Edge(dis, dos, objectID);
            }
        }, idListQuery);
    }
}
interface ObjectFactory<V> {
    V newObject(String objectID);
}
```

EDIT: I hadone idea of how I could implement this in C# but I have realised it is not possible:

```
static class Edges : UpdatableRepository<Edge>, ObjectFactory<Edge> {

    public override Edge newObject(String objectID) {
        return new Edge(dis, dos, objectID);
    }
    public Edges(BinaryReader dis, BinaryWriter dos, StringListQ idListQuery) {
        base(this.newObject(String objectID, idListQuery);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

NEW EDIT:

I keep receiving the suggestion that this topic is a duplicate of [C# vs JAVA instance of Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802227/c-sharp-vs-java-instance-of-interface) and nobody is answering this. However, I still don't know how to proceed, even after reading that thread and the documentation indicated in it's answer. For this reason, I would like to ask for help again.

Comment: Shall I make my class Edge implement ObjectFactory, redefine the newObject method and then make `base(newObject(objectID),idListQuery) `?

Comment: The point of `ObjectFactory` is that `UpdatableRepository` cannot create objects of it's child classes. This helper construct allows it to call the `newObject` method without knowing anything about classes like `Edges`. The Edge class should IMO not extend ObjectFactory.

Comment: @zapl Sorry, I don't get to understant your last comment.

Comment: I don't know C# but what the duplicate question means: the `UpdatableRepository` class should have a constructor that takes a delegate (I think `Func<string, T>` or so would be the type) instead of the `ObjectFactory`. That delegate takes a string object id and returns a new T object, exactly like the `T ObjectFactory#newObject(String)` method of the factory. Then you call it somehow like `base((id) => new Edge(id));` (or whatever the correct C# syntax is.) and you have the equivalent in c#